# How to create simplest p2p remote desktop OR any Robot(Java) equivalent in python 

Tags: python, operating-system, remote-desktop, p2p

I want to create a simplest remote desktop application using p2p communication.
I did created one small p2p program in python.

My Idea is-

- Transmit screenshots of remote computer periodically
- Transmit keyboard and mouse events wrapped in xml to remote desktop.

Problem-

I could transmit a information for keyboard and mouse events to remote computer and it will be received. But how should remote program reflect those events to remote machine. I mean how should remote program communicate with operating system.

OS: windows xp

Ok is there any equivalent of [Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)(Java) in python to control mouse and keyboard events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the keyboard and the mouse with python on Windows by calling the win32 apis: [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx) thanks to ctypes